# delete a dynamically created button android

Tags: java, android, button, android-linearlayout

Ok, what I'm trying to do is, something like a tag search function.
What I did was create Button ArrayList, and whenever a user tries to input ",", it automatically creates a button and inserts it into the ArrayList, which ultimately registers to the LinearLayout.

It creates well, but does not delete well.
I get the error that the index is out of bounds, but was in no luck of finding out which statement should I use. Could you help me?
Thx in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Button> tagCollection = null;
private LinearLayout llTagCollection = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tagCollection = new ArrayList<Button>();
    initView();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void initView() {
    final EditText etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_SEARCH);
    // final TextView tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_RESULT);
    llTagCollection = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL_BUTTON_COLLECTION);


    View currentView = new View(getApplicationContext());
    /*
    if(tagCollection.size() != 0) {
        tagCollection.get(currentView.getId()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tagCollection.remove(tagCollection.get(v.getId()));
                Log.e("Removed", String.valueOf(tagCollection.remove(tagCollection.get(v.getId()))));
                // tagCollection.remove(this);
                llTagCollection.removeAllViews();
                int i = 0;
                while (i < (tagCollection.size())) {
                    llTagCollection.addView(tagCollection.get(i));
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    */

    TextWatcher tagWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String convertedCharSequence = s.toString();
            Log.e("ConvertedString", convertedCharSequence);
            if (convertedCharSequence.length() > 0) {
                String subString = convertedCharSequence.substring(convertedCharSequence.length() - 1);
                Log.e("SubStringPosition", subString);

                if (subString.equals(",")) {
                    // tvResult.setText(etSearch.getText().toString());
                    Button bTagButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    bTagButton.setId(tagCollection.size());
                    bTagButton.setText(etSearch.getText().toString());
                    bTagButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    bTagButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    /*
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    if(tagCollection.size() != 0){
                        rlLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, tagCollection.get(0).getId());
                    }
                    bTagButton.setLayoutParams(rlLayoutParams);
                    */

                    bTagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            tagCollection.remove(tagCollection.indexOf(this));

                            llTagCollection.removeAllViews();
                            int i = 0;
                            while (i < (tagCollection.size())) {
                                if(tagCollection.get(i) != null){
                                    llTagCollection.addView(tagCollection.get(i));
                                }

                                i += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    tagCollection.add(bTagButton);

                    llTagCollection.removeAllViews();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < (tagCollection.size())) {
                        llTagCollection.addView(tagCollection.get(i));
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    // setContentView(rlTagCollection);
                    etSearch.setText("");
                    etSearch.setSelection(0);
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(tagWatcher);
}
```

}

Comment: link the logger output

Comment: I solved it using indexOfChild function. It kept on throwing me indexOutOfBounds error. Thx

Comment: @DevMGL: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially since you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using indexOfChild function. It kept on throwing me indexOutOfBounds error. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Because of the reputations, I can not add comment. SO I post here.

In the button click listener:

```
bTagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            tagCollection.remove(tagCollection.indexOf(this));

                            llTagCollection.removeAllViews();
                            int i = 0;
                            while (i < (tagCollection.size())) {
                                if (tagCollection.get(i) != null) {
                                    llTagCollection.addView(tagCollection.get(i));
                                }

                                i += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

You remove the button by `tagCollection.remove(tagCollection.indexOf(this));`. Here `this` means the `OnClickListener` instance, not the button clicked. SO you should remove buttons by：

```
tagCollection.remove(tagCollection.indexOf(v));
```